# Local Multiplayer in Xbox Live Creators Program

Tags: xbox-live

The developer program overview docs (https://developer.microsoft.com/de-de/games/xbox/docs/xboxlive/xbox-live/developer-program-overview) say, that Multiplayer is NOT supported in the Creators Program, but is this only related to the Online-Multiplayer and I'm still able to login multiple users, so they can play together / against each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, multiple local users is supported.  We're adding multiple local user support to the Xbox Live Unity asset in an upcoming release.

Here's the link to Windows Store policies:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn764944.aspx#pol_10_13